# React Multiple Dropdown component doesn't close when clicking on the blank area

Tags: reactjs

A Dropdown component that, when clicked, displays a dropdown menu, and when clicking outside the dropdown area, closes the dropdown.

Now there is an issue that I have spent a long time trying to solve:

Using only one Dropdown component, clicking in a blank area successfully closes the dropdown.

However, if there are two or three Dropdown components, clicking in a blank area does not close the dropdown.

My expected outcome: Multiple Dropdown components, where clicking on the blank area should close the dropdown menus.

The current issue is: For a single Dropdown component, clicking on the blank area closes it; however, for multiple Dropdown components, clicking on the blank area does not close them.

How to solve this problem?

The Live Demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-cizh35?file=src%2FApp.tsx

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

type DropdownProps = {
  className?: string;
  handleSelectLanguage?: (language: string) => void;
  text: string;
  items: string[];
};

export const Dropdown: React.FC<DropdownProps> = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState(props.text);

  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setText(props.text);
  }, [props.text]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('open1: ', open);

    function handleOutsideClick(e: MouseEvent) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();

      console.log('open2: ', open);

      const [target] = e.composedPath();

      console.log('target:', !ref.current?.contains(target as Node), open);

      if (!ref.current?.contains(target as Node) && open) {
        console.log('2');
        setOpen(false);
      }
    }

    document.body.addEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick, false);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick, false);
    };
  }, [open]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={`dropdown relative ${props.className}`} ref={ref}>
        <button
          className="w-full flex justify-center items-center rounded text-sm px-2 py-1 hover:bg-[#e3e3e3] border"
          style={{ display: 'flex' }}
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          <span>{text}</span>
          <span className="test relative top-[1px] ml-1">
            <svg
              // stroke="currentColor"
              viewBox="0 0 12 12"
              fill="currentColor"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              className="w-3 h-3"
            >
              <path d="M8.77814 4.00916C8.58288 3.8139 8.26629 3.8139 8.07103 4.00916L5.89096 6.18923L3.77338 4.07164C3.57811 3.87638 3.26153 3.87638 3.06627 4.07164L2.71272 4.42519C2.51745 4.62046 2.51745 4.93704 2.71272 5.1323L5.54114 7.96073C5.7364 8.15599 6.05299 8.15599 6.24825 7.96073L6.6018 7.60718C6.61932 7.58966 6.63527 7.57116 6.64965 7.55186L9.13169 5.06982C9.32695 4.87456 9.32695 4.55797 9.13169 4.36271L8.77814 4.00916Z" />
            </svg>
          </span>
        </button>
        {open && (
          <ul
            className={`dropdown-ul z-2 absolute mt-1 w-full rounded bg-[#efefef] ring-1 ring-gray-300 max-h-52 overflow-y-auto`}
          >
            {props.items.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li
                  key={index}
                  className="relative flex cursor-default select-none items-center rounded-sm px-2 py-1.5 text-xs outline-none hover:bg-[#e3e3e3]"
                  onClick={() => {
                    setOpen(false);
                    setText(item);
                    console.log('item: ', item);
                    props.handleSelectLanguage &&
                      props.handleSelectLanguage(item);
                  }}
                >
                  {item}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

---

Unable to resolve this issue, I used a third-party library.

https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/elements/dropdowns

Comment: In case of the second button do you expect that more than one dropdown can be opened at a same time or only one dropdown will be opened at a same time ?

Comment: @santra72 My expected outcome: For multiple Dropdown components, clicking on the blank area should close the dropdown menus. But I don't know where the issue is in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your component loads, you add three event listeners to `document.body` for each dropdown (one, two, three) in this order:

```
- one (`handleOutsideClick` added by dropdown one)
- two (`handleOutsideClick` added by dropdown two)
- three (`handleOutsideClick` added by dropdown three)
```

Now if you decide to open dropdown one for example by clicking on it, you update its `open` state from `true` to `false`, causing your component to rerender. After your component is done rerendering, it:

- Calls the cleanup function from your `useEffect()` for dropdown one, removing the event-listener added to `document.body` for `one`
- Invokes the `useEffect()` callback since `open`, state changed, adding the click event listener back to `document.body` for dropdown one.

Now the order of the click events added to `document.body` has changed since we removed dropdown one's click event listener (`one`) and added it back (`one'`), and so instead it looks like this:

```
- two
- three
- one'
```

This means that when you try and click outside of dropdown one to "close" it, the callback for dropdown two (`two`) will be invoked first since it's now the first callback added to `document.body`. Dropdown `two`s callback only knows about its `open` state (currently `false`), which is why you see `false` being logged. The important part here is that the callbacks for `three` and `one'` don't get invoked after `two` is invoked as you're calling `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` when `two` is called, which prevents these subsequent event handlers from being invoked. Instead, to fix this, remove your `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` call as you do want these callbacks to be invoked so that they can properly update their associated dropdowns `open` state to close the dropdown if needed.

```js
function handleOutsideClick(e: MouseEvent) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

You'll notice that if you click on one dropdown and then another, the previous one will close. If you don't want that behaviour, you can call `stopPropagation();` in your `handleClick()` which stops any of callbacks added to `document.body` from being invoked (and thus potentially closing one of the dropdowns) as the click event won't bubble up to `body`:

```
const handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  setOpen(open => !open);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make these changes in the second `useEffect` hook call. This closes the modal when clicked outside.

See if that fits your requirement.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('open1: ', open);

    function handleOutsideClick(e: MouseEvent) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();

      console.log('open2: ', open);

      const [target] = e.composedPath();

      console.log('target:', !ref.current?.contains(target as Node), open);

      if (!ref.current?.contains(target as Node) && open) {
        console.log('2');
        setOpen(false);
      }
    }

// added a condition if the dropdown is open then only add the event listener
    if (open) {
      document.body.addEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick, false);
    }

    return () => {

// added a condition if the dropdown is open then only remove the event listener before the component gets unmounted
      if (open) {
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick, false);
      }
    };
  }, [open]);
```